# how to get utf 8 encoded file with php

Tags: php, file, utf-8

I want to get a `.html` or `.txt` file from a folder with PHP, but this file is UTF-8 encoded, and if I use `$html=file_get_contents('somewhere/somewhat.html');` and after that I `echo $html;` then this won't be UTF-8 encoded. I see many "�" in the text. Any idea? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert it to UTF8 yourselves. To do that use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) and [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) PHP functions.

Like this,

```
$html=file_get_contents('somewhere/somewhat.html');
$html=mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
echo $html;
```

> **mb_convert_encoding()** converts character encoding
>   **mb_detect_encoding()** detects character encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try to use iconv on your string:
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.iconv.php

Other solution:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Or:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php